# Flutter on Linux: "flutter run" fails with NoClassDefFoundError org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.pom.java.LanguageLevel

Tags: flutter, android-studio

After upgrading to `Android Studio 22.2.1 Patch 1` and `openJDK-20` on `Ubuntu 2022.10`, calling `flutter run` in `VS Code` fails with:

```
e: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.pom.java.LanguageLevel
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.core.CoreLanguageLevelProjectExtension.<init>(CoreLanguageLevelProjectExtension.java:26)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.core.JavaCoreProjectEnvironment.<init>(JavaCoreProjectEnvironment.java:42)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreProjectEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreProjectEnvironment.kt:26)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$ProjectEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:118)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:420)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:226)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:152)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:371)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:105)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:249)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:38)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:80)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:92)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:602)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1644)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':location:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              7.8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Odd thing is, the app does not even use Kotlin and it's still running well on MacOS, so this looks like there's something wrong with the development system, rather than the app.

**Edit:**

- Updating `ndkVersion` to the latest version had unfortunately no effect.
- Deleting the folders `build` and `.gradle` had no effect neither.

Do you have any ideas what could cause this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

**Update the Kotlin version . build.gradle**
[NDK Downloads](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads)

```
 android {
        compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
        ndkVersion "25.2.9519653"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Setting `ndkVersion` to the latest version had unfortunately no effect.